# When blood flow to the brain increases during exercise, how many hours does it stay this way afterwards?

Tags: home-exercise, blood-flow, brain

It is a well-known fact that the blood flow to the brain quite increased during an exercise because of the blood vessels dilation. How long does it stay this way?

I want to try short exercises and pair them with learning (watching lectures reading textbooks). I noticed that my learning abilities are significantly enhanced for about 40 min or so. Where can I find precise measurements on that topic, and maybe on how much serotonin/dopamin/epinephrine is enhanced too, graphs?

Comment: Are you a very average person that does a very average work out that always has an average day? If so, you might get some value out of some measurements taken from other people in lab circumstances. Otherwise, what do you need to know? You know your personal peak. If you know enough math to understand any study, you will have a rough idea. If you don't, you will not take away useful lessons from reading scientific articles. This question is fine  imo, but still, ask yourself if it's really useful and will help you in any way.

Answer (score 3):

-Pub med actually has graphs on this. "Brain activity after physical activity" i believe is what I typed in.
  - I joined stack exchange almost 5 minutes ago.. So, Please be patient with me! I am trying to add a link to this study. However,  I am unsure of the best way to do that at the moment.
  - (I did take the tour but the method explained has not worked for me, so far. I'm sure it is user error.) I will update asap.
    -I for one, loved your question.  It piqued my curiosity greatly!

Comment: Thank you very much! You can send the link to the research here in the comment and  I will add it as a solution